# How to convert json file to List<MyClass>

Tags: c#, json, deserialization

I am trying to create a log file in json format from a List.
my class for list is

```
public class ChunkItem
    {
        public int start { get; set; }
        public int end { get; set; }
    }
 public class DownloadItem
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string fname { get; set; }
        public string downloadPath { get; set; }
        public int chunkCount { get; set; }
        public ChunkItem[] chunks { get; set; }
        public DownloadItem(int _id, string _fname, string _downloadPath, int _chunkCount, ChunkItem[] _chunks)
        {
            id = _id;
            fname = _fname;
            downloadPath = _downloadPath;
            chunkCount = _chunkCount;
            chunks = _chunks;
        }

    }
```

creating a json file from this class works fine

```
ChunkItem[] chunks = new ChunkItem[2];
chunks[0] = new ChunkItem();
chunks[0].start = 0;
chunks[0].end = 0;
chunks[1] = new ChunkItem();
chunks[1].start = 0;
chunks[1].end = 0;
List<DownloadItem> lst = new List<DownloadItem>();
lst.Add(new DownloadItem(0, "", "", 2, chunks));
lst.Add(new DownloadItem(1, "aaa", "sss", 2, chunks));
lst.Add(new DownloadItem(2, "bbb", "ddd", 2, chunks));
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(lst);
System.IO.File.WriteAllText(logPath, json);
```

I want to read the file to same class list and do some updates or add new lines 
I can read the file to a string but cannot create a new list
how can I convert string (read json file) to `List<DownloadItem> new list`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to read all the contends from the file and [deserialize](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/Overload_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConvert_DeserializeObject.htm) the json string to `List<DownloadItem>`

```
var jsonData = File.ReadAllText(filePath)
var list = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<DownloadItem>>(jsonData);
```

Comment: thanks I tried something similar but 
```.DeserializeObject<List<DownloadItem>> ``` is the key 
I used  ```List < DownloadItem > lst= JsonConvert.DeserializeObject < DownloadItem >(json);
or 
 List < DownloadItem > lst= JsonConvert.DeserializeObject < List > (json);```
 the key is to combine both :D

Answer (score 0):

I use Newtonsoft, where creating the instances and filling them is simple

```
var result = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyClass>(jsonString);
```

Answer (score 0):

Clas DownloadItem is missing a default parameterless constructor.

Comment: Do I really need that ?